# Open an unspecifiable Folder with applescript

Tags: automation, applescript, keyboard-maestro

I'm trying to write an AppleScript for a Keyboard Maestro Macro, which opens the pictures folder of a camera SD or CF Card in an existing Finder window. 
This is my current code, which opens the mounted Volume.

```
tell application "Keyboard Maestro Engine"
    set KMVarPath to get value of variable "path"
end tell



set the_string to "/Volumes/" & KMVarPath
set the_path to (POSIX file the_string) as string

tell application "Finder"
    activate
    if window 1 exists then
        set target of window 1 to the_path
    else
        reveal the_path
    end if
end tell
```

The problem is those folders are called ie 276ND2XS or 105ND800. I'd like to specify the 'suffix' (ND2XS/ND800) and open the folder with the highest 'prefix' number.

Is there a way to do that?

And for convenience, is there a way to check, whether the volume is an SD or CF Card? Or do I have to check via the name (NIKON D2XS / NIKON D800)?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to look for shell command : system_profiler SPStorageDataType
You can use it in a "do shell script" command in your applescript.
This command gives you, among others,  the name all connected storage types (USD, SD card, hard drive), the mount point (example /volumes/myDisk), the physical drive device name and media name, and the protocol (USB, SATA, ATA,...). I don't have CF Card to test, but it should give you a way to detect. As example, When I use SD card, Media Name is "APPLE SD Card Reader Media".

Once you know the volume, you can get the folder with highest counter name with :

```
set the_path to choose folder -- this is just for my test ! replace by your path "Volumes:..." as alias

set the_Folder to ""
set the_Highest to 0
tell application "Finder"
set my_List to name of every folder in the_path whose (name contains "D2XS") or (name contains "ND800")
repeat with a_folder in my_List
    try
        set the_Num to (text 1 thru 3 of a_folder) as integer
    on error
        set the_Num to 0
    end try
    if the_Num > the_Highest then
        set the_Highest to the_Num
        set the_Folder to a_folder
    end if
end repeat
end tell

log "num=" & the_Num
log "fodler=" & (the_Folder)
```

Comment: Thanks for the information. But my main question was if i can somehow prompt the DCIM subfolder xxxND800 with the highes number.

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood. I have updated my answer with small code to get highest folder number. Performance is OK as long as number of folders is reasonable (<200)